# Finding User with Auth - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to find the logged in user in my application using `Auth` but i get `trying to get property of non-object` which i understand clearly that it is returning null.

In my code below, an event triggers my webhook and post is sent to the address below. The function `orderCreateWebhook` triggers but  that is where the error comes from..

The line `$get_template = Order::where('id', Auth::user()->id);`. Why is `Auth` returning null please? I am logged as well because i use auth in this same controller for another function which works fine.

Is it because it a webhook ?

**Controller**

```
public function registerOrderCreateWebhook(Request $request)
    {

            $shop = "feas.myshopify.com";
            $token = "8f43d89a64e922d7d343c1173f6d";
            $shopify = Shopify::setShopUrl($shop)->setAccessToken($token);
            Shopify::setShopUrl($shop)->setAccessToken($token)->post("admin/webhooks.json", ['webhook' => 
             ['topic' => 'orders/create',
             'address' => 'https://larashop.domain.com/order-create-webhook',
             'format' => 'json'
             ]
            ]);
    }




     public function orderCreateWebhook(Request $request)
    {

         $get_template = Order::where('id', Auth::user()->id);

        $baseurl = "https://apps.domain.net/smsapi";
        $query = "?key=7e3e4d4a6cfebc08eadc&to=number&msg=message&sender_id=Shopify";
        $final_uri = $baseurl.$query;
        $response = file_get_contents($final_uri);
        header ("Content-Type:text/xml");

    }
```

Comment: How are you authenticating the user? btw, you can access to the user id with just this: `auth()->id()`

Comment: Webhooks are coming from the shopify server, not your users computer. As a result, a webhook only has the information that shopify passes to it, nothing else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function `registerOrderCreateWebhook` you appear to be making a request to shopify api and providing your webhook as the address which shopify will redirect the user to upon success. If this is correct, that request does not know about the user who generated the original request that made the api request since the request is coming from a completely different origin.

You would need to pass some key along with the url and then obtain the user within `orderCreateWebhook`. Something like:

```
Shopify::setShopUrl($shop)->setAccessToken($token)->post("admin/webhooks.json", 
['webhook' => 
    ['topic' => 'orders/create',
     'address' => 'https://larashop.domain.com/order-create-webhook/some-unique-key',
     'format' => 'json'
    ]
 ]);
```

My suggestion would be to have a unique hash stored somewhere that relates back to the user in your system, perhaps a column in your users table. I wouldn't use the `user_id` for security reasons. So you would end up with something like:

```
//route
Route::get('/order-create-webhook/{uniqueKey}', 'YourController@orderCreateWebhook');
//or
Route::post('/order-create-webhook/{uniqueKey}', 'YourController@orderCreateWebhook');
// depending on the request type used by api which calls this endpoint

// controller function
public function orderCreateWebhook($uniqueKey, Request $request)
{

     $user = User::where('unique_key', $uniqueKey)->first();
     $get_template = Order::where('id', Auth::user()->id);

     $baseurl = "https://apps.domain.net/smsapi";
     $query = "?key=7e3e4d4a6cfebc08eadc&to=number&msg=message&sender_id=Shopify";
     $final_uri = $baseurl.$query;
     $response = file_get_contents($final_uri);
     header ("Content-Type:text/xml");

}
```

Comment: `Route::get('/order-create-webhook/{uniqueKey}', 'YourController@orderCreateWebhook');` i thought this route is suppose to be a post not a get

Comment: That would depend on the request being made by shopify to the url. If they are doing a post request then you would want to use `Route::post()`. Updated answer.

Comment: Shopify does a post request. I have exactly done what you have but the webhook doesn't trigger anymore

Comment: Sounds like something isn't right with your route. Can you provide your updated route?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it because it a webhook ?

Yes, you can't use sessions in a webhook. It's the shopify server which is making the call. You should read the doc, it may exist a way to give an unique identifier in your call to shopify api and get it back in the webhook to find your user associated.

Comment: this is the url of your webhook ?      'address' => 'https://larashop.domain.com/order-create-webhook/some-unique-key',

If you add a parameter in the url ? uid=myid should works

Answer (score 0):

just use this to get authenticated user
use the facade in your class/Controller

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth

public function getAuthUser(){
    $user = Auth::user()
    if(!is_null($user)
   {
    //user is authenticated
   }
  else 
   {
    // no user
   }
}
```